# Rewrite configure to redirect directory to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have domain.com/forums but I need help redirecting the forums to sub.domain.com

Below works but I end up with

```
sub.domain/forums/topic-name-here

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^\/?forum\/.* 
RewriteRule ^\/?forum\/(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

P.S. i using "/?" because i forget REQUEST_URI format :(